# how do I push my local master branch to an updated remote repository without losing the changes?

Tags: git, github

I have pushed every change I made to the GitHub repository, but a collaborator has been working on the design with the version that doesn't have any of the changes that I recently made and pushed to git hub. How do I combine what the collaborator has done with the version in the repository without losing any of the changes?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand but you can commit your changes and do `git pull` or `git pull --rebase` with changes pulled by collaborator to remote repo. If you dont want commit your changes yet, do `git stash` and `git pull` and `git stash pop`take you changes back to the stage

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this depends on who pushed their changes to the remote (Github) first.

If you pushed your changes first, then the collaborator will have to do a `git pull`. It will then ask them to merge their changes with yours. Once those are resolved, then the collaborator will be able to use `git push` to push their changes to the remote (Github) and you will be able to pull them.

If the collaborator pushed their changes first, then you will be the one who has to pull, merge, and push (roles reversed from previous scenario).

Answer (score 0):

As you have said, you have pushed all the changes to the git repository.
And then you said that your collaborator has also pushed it to the repository.

1. Assuming that it has been done correctly, (no conflicts) you do not have to worry as both your's and your collaborator's changes are present on github. You might be able to see this in commits.
2. If it is not done correctly, meaning, one of you who has tried to push it lastly, might have gotten a merge conflict. In that case, you have to resolve those conflicts by doing:

   ```
   git pull
   ```

   And, put the correct code where the conflict/s has happened.

You can check out the current situation in commits section.

In case, you can ask specific queries related to this, as the question is not clear enough. Hope this helps.